# Sending multiple medias with tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to make a Twitter bot with tweepy. It's actually my first twitter BOT, I'm kinda new to it.

I have a list of medias containing the path of each image I need to send.
I am able to send tweets with text

```
api.update_status(status="some text")
```

Or sending tweets with one single media

```
api.update_with_media(filename, status="some text with media")
```

But I need to send many images with my tweet. 
I heard that I need to upload my files first but I don't know how to integrate them in the tweet. 
Or maybe there is another way of doing it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case you want to upload multiple images, you can use Twitter API's [`media/upload`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) via Tweepy's `api.media_upload()` method.

This method returns a response object containing `media_id` and you can attach multiple `media_ids` to `api.update_status()`.

So the code you may want to write is like this:

```
# Upload images and get media_ids
filenames = ['1.png', '2.png', ...]
media_ids = []
for filename in filenames:
     res = api.media_upload(filename)
     media_ids.append(res.media_id)

# Tweet with multiple images
api.update_status(status='many images!✨', media_ids=media_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! 
I am actually using quotes wich are quite simple to use. I may help a lot of people though.

Comment: `media_ids = [api.media_upload(f).media_id_string for f in filenames]`

Comment: This solution is prompting the following error: `update_status_with_media() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename' 
` Any idea ?

Comment: @bog Hello. According to the docs (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.update_status_with_media), it seems like `update_status_with_media()` has different parameters. It was deprecated so maybe you'd like consider use `media_update()` and `update_status()`.

Comment: @shuuji3 Thanks, this worked for me: `msg = "Test with 2 img"
pics = ("ninja.jpg", "ninja2.jpg")
media_ids = [api.media_upload(i).media_id_string for i in pics]
api.update_status(status=msg, media_ids=media_ids)`

Comment: @bog Glad to hear that! 

Comment: @shuuji3 hey i tried the same thing but i keep getting the error 'media_ids parameter is invalid' any idea whys this coming up?